# IIS 7 Request routing

Tags: iis-7, proxy

Not sure the title is right.  I have my site configured in IIS7 and I have another partner site which runs on a different port eg. http:// localhost:1234 /mysite.  Can I have my parent site to have a virtual site http:// localhost /mysite to route requests to the partner site http://localhost:1234 /mysite.  **I should not redirect**  but I should basically proxy the requests.  Any help here is appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use Application Request Routing (ARR).  It's a small add-on for IIS7 and works as a reverse proxy.  It's great, and will do exactly what you're talking about.  Find it at [iis.net](http://iis.net)